# Converting a nested JSON to CSV in Python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I would like to convert nested json to a csv file.
I am receiving the json from Rest API.
The fields in csv should look like following.
daterange_start,daterange_end,clicks,impressions,pivotvalues.
I am new to Python and JSON so would love to get some help.
Here is the sample json.

```
{
    "elements": [
        {
            "dateRange": {
                "start": {
                    "month": 3,
                    "year": 2019,
                    "day": 3
                },
                "end": {
                    "month": 3,
                    "year": 2019,
                    "day": 3
                }
            },
            "clicks": 11,
            "impressions": 2453,
            "pivotValues": [
                "urn:li:sponsoredCampaign:1234567"
            ]
        },
        {
            "dateRange": {
                "start": {
                    "month": 3,
                    "year": 2019,
                    "day": 7
                },
                "end": {
                    "month": 3,
                    "year": 2019,
                    "day": 7
                }
            },
            "clicks": 1,
            "impressions": 629,
            "pivotValues": [
                "urn:li:sponsoredCampaign:1234565"
            ]
        },
        {
            "dateRange": {
                "start": {
                    "month": 3,
                    "year": 2019,
                    "day": 21
                },
                "end": {
                    "month": 3,
                    "year": 2019,
                    "day": 21
                }
            },
            "clicks": 3,
            "impressions": 154,
            "pivotValues": [
                "urn:li:sponsoredCampaign:1323516"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "paging": {
        "count": 10,
        "start": 0,
        "links": []
    }
}
```

Comment: will `"pivotvalues"` always be a list of 1 element?

Comment: Yes. Only need data from that element.

Comment: sorry, I wasnt clear. What I'm asking is will you ever see `"pivotValues" = [value1, value2, value3]`...or is it ALWAYS,  `"pivotValues" = [value1]`?

Comment: It is always one value

Comment: awesome. i fixed my solution then below (I still left it just incase multiple do show up, but shouldn't affect the output if it is just 1). That should work/clean it up for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `json_normalize`. The only issue is the `"pivotValues"` is a list. So not sure what you'd want there, or if there are more than 1 element within those lists. If it's just one element, you can just easily process that column. If it can have multiple elements, you can eaither create a new row for each element (meaning you have multiple rows with the same data, except different `pivotValues`, or you could extend each row to have each `pivotValues`, but then would have nulls with those lists as different lengths.

I also added on there (seeing that the `pivotValues` all have same prefix), splitting out hat value for you in case yo needed it.

**Given:**

```
data = {
    "elements": [
        {
            "dateRange": {
                "start": {
                    "month": 3,
                    "year": 2019,
                    "day": 3
                },
                "end": {
                    "month": 3,
                    "year": 2019,
                    "day": 3
                }
            },
            "clicks": 11,
            "impressions": 2453,
            "pivotValues": [
                "urn:li:sponsoredCampaign:1234567"
            ]
        },
        {
            "dateRange": {
                "start": {
                    "month": 3,
                    "year": 2019,
                    "day": 7
                },
                "end": {
                    "month": 3,
                    "year": 2019,
                    "day": 7
                }
            },
            "clicks": 1,
            "impressions": 629,
            "pivotValues": [
                "urn:li:sponsoredCampaign:1234565"
            ]
        },
        {
            "dateRange": {
                "start": {
                    "month": 3,
                    "year": 2019,
                    "day": 21
                },
                "end": {
                    "month": 3,
                    "year": 2019,
                    "day": 21
                }
            },
            "clicks": 3,
            "impressions": 154,
            "pivotValues": [
                "urn:li:sponsoredCampaign:1323516"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "paging": {
        "count": 10,
        "start": 0,
        "links": []
    }
}
```

**Code:**

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize


df = json_normalize(data['elements'])
df['pivotValues'] = df.pivotValues.apply(pd.Series).add_prefix('pivotValues_')
df['pivotValues_stripped'] = df['pivotValues'].str.rsplit(':',1, expand=True)[1]

df.to_csv('path/filename.csv', index=False)
```

**Output:**

```
print (results.to_string())
   clicks  dateRange.end.day  dateRange.end.month  dateRange.end.year  dateRange.start.day  dateRange.start.month  dateRange.start.year  impressions                       pivotValues pivotValues_stripped
0      11                  3                    3                2019                    3                      3                  2019         2453  urn:li:sponsoredCampaign:1234567              1234567
1       1                  7                    3                2019                    7                      3                  2019          629  urn:li:sponsoredCampaign:1234565              1234565
2       3                 21                    3                2019                   21                      3                  2019          154  urn:li:sponsoredCampaign:1323516              1323516
```

Comment: Is this normalized data can be directly added to a database table ?

Comment: I don't see why it couldn't.

Answer (score 2):

You can load and parse the json in python with:

```
import json
y = json.loads(x)
```

`y` will be a python dict. Now loop over `y['elements']` and create a list with your desired fields. For example extract the year of start and end dates:

```
list_for_csv=[]
for e in y['elements']:
    list_for_csv.append([e['daterange']['start']['year'],e['daterange']['end']['year']])
```

Then use numpy to save as csv:

```
import numpy as np
for_csv = np.asarray(list_for_csv)
np.savetxt("your_file.csv", for_csv, delimiter=",")
```